# How to make casperjs continue instead of exit on exception?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

When I use CasperJS to handle web, I find a strange case. The program exits on exception even if I use try-catch block!
My code is as follows. I hope the program can continue running next loop. However, when the `iframe` cannot be found, an exception throws like `CasperError: Frame number "1" is out of bounds.` and the whole program exits. The `myStore` function in catch block is also not run.

Is there anybody can help us?

```
try {
    // find the iframe and then fill in the message
    casper.withFrame(1, function() {
        casper.evaluate(function(message) {
            // some function code
        });
        casper.wait(1000, function() {
            myStore(stores, index+1);  
            // when the iframe not found, function myStroe will not be run
        });
    });
} catch (err) {
    output(false, "error=" + err.message);
    myStore(stores, index+1);  // myStroe will not be run on Exception
}
```

I try the example given by Artjom B but it does not work.

```
var frameExists = false;
casper.withFrame(1, function() {
    frameExists = true;
    casper.evaluate(function(message) {
        // some function code
    });
});
casper.wait(3000, function() {
    if (frameExists) {
        // the program run this branch and got stuck in the nonexistent selector since the frame is not found.
        casper.click("input#send");  
        // some function code
        output(true, "index=" + index + ";storeId=" + store.id + ";succeeded");
        myStore(stores, index+1);
    } else {
        output(false, "index=" + index + ";storeId=" + store.id + ";error=" + err.message);
        myStore(stores, index+1);
    }
});
```

It is very strange. I don't know why the program run into the wrong branch with `frameExists === true`.

Answer (score 1):

There is the handy little option called [`exitOnError`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#exitonerror):

At the beginning:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    exitOnError: false
});
```

or later:

```
casper.options.exitOnError = false;
```

---

If you want `myStore()` to be run regardless of the existence of the frame, you can do something like this:

```
casper.then(function(){
    var frameExists = false;
    // find the iframe and then fill in the message
    casper.withFrame(1, function() {
        frameExists = true;
        casper.evaluate(function(message) {
            // some function code
        });
        casper.wait(1000, function() {
            myStore(stores, index+1);  
            // when the iframe not found, function myStroe will not be run
        });
    });
    casper.then(function(){
        if (!frameExists) {
            output(false, "error=" + err.message);
            myStore(stores, index+1);  // myStroe will not be run on Exception
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I want `myStore(stores, index+1)` to be running after exception. But now the program got stuck without any output.

Comment: Many thanks. I try your example but see no error output. `output(false, "error=" + err.message);` is not be executed and my program still got stuck without any output.